# Finding length of line giving answer in ratio

Tags: geometry

I have the question "Find the coordinates of the point that divides the line joining A(2,4) to B(-3,9) internally in the ratio 1:4".

I have worked out the midpoint of these two points and I got (-1/2, 13/2) for the X and Y coordinates, however, I do not know how to put this into the ratio 1:4. When checking the solutions the answer should be (1, 5).

Comment: Consider the $x$- and $y$-coordinates respectively:
what numbers divide the intervals $[2,-3]$ and $[4,9]$ in the ratio $1:4$?
Once you have both, piece the coordinates together to get the answer.

Comment: Wait, do you want the length of the line, or the coordinates? Asking for the length of the line is in the title, while the coordinates of the point is in the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the vector $\mathop {OP}\limits^ \to   = \mathop {OA}\limits^ \to   + \mathop {t\,AB}\limits^ \to$ describes the segment connecting $A$ to $B$.
When $t=0$ you get point $A$, and when $t=1$ you get point $B$.
So with $t=1/4$ you get a point which has a distance from $A$ equal to $1/4$ of the *total segment* if the ratio $1:4$ is intended in that way.
If instead the ratio is intended as among the two pieces, as it seems to be in your case, then of course you should take $t=1/5$, which will give the answer you cite as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the distance formula, we get the line as $5\sqrt2$. So let $a=\text{shorter segment}$ and $b=\text{the longer segment}$. So we have the following: $$\frac ab=\frac 14\\a+b=5\sqrt{2}\tag{1}$$

Solving the first equation of $(1)$ gives us $b=4a$. Substituting that into the second equation gives us $$a+4a=5\sqrt2\tag{2}$$ with $a=\sqrt2$ being the only solution. Therefore, $b=4\sqrt2$.

---

If you want the coordinate, then just simply use the distance formula to get the coordinate. $(1,5)$